# Wget commmand not found

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wget

I tried installing wget. It says wget is up to date. But when I use wget it says command not found.

[image]

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/wget` work? ... What is the output of `type -a wget`

Comment: No it doesn't work. Returned wget: not found

Comment: Please include the output of `apt policy wget` ... Please [edit] <-- (Click Here) your question to add that.

Comment: Ok. I just did that.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt reinstall wget` and then try again with the `wget` command to see if it works.

Comment: It worked finally. Thanks so much mate

Comment: Did it give you any error message  ... I mean `sudo apt reinstall wget` .... And please run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure wget` and see if it fixes it or prints any messages.

Comment: It worked. The sudo apt reinstall wget. Didn't no there was a reinstall function. Been on this issues for days which you solved on just minutes.  Thanks mate.

Comment: You're welcome ... `wget` seems installed on your system indeed but the executable under `/usr/bin` looks missing (probably deleted by mistake) and `sudo apt reinstall wget` or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure wget` should put that executable back.

Comment: @Terrance `reinstall` is an alias for `install --reinstall` and can be used as a command with `apt` ... Please see [`man apt-get`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/apt-get.8.html)

Comment: @Raffa Ah, My bad!

Comment: hello, i realized i can't move a file directory to home

Answer (score 1):

Is the `wget` executable in a directory on your PATH?

Run:

```
echo $PATH
```

... to see what your `PATH` is.

Run:

```
dpkg-query -L wget
```

... to get a list of the files in the `wget` package. I expect one of them to be `/usr/bin/wget`

If `/usr/bin` is not in your `PATH`, the command will not be found.

Also, `wget` seems installed on your system indeed but the executable under `/usr/bin` might be missing (probably deleted by mistake) and in that case either:

```
sudo apt reinstall wget
```

... or:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wget
```

should put that executable back and fix it.

Comment: Might be worth noting that `/bin` is linked to `/usr/bin` and thus if no `/usr/bin` is present in the search path but, `/bin` is, then that might suffice as well.

Comment: /usr/bin is there

Comment: I edited your answer a bit :-) ... I hope you don't mind ... Please feel free to undo my edit if you don't agree with it and I would understand it.

Comment: The edit of my answer by @raffa is very helpful, both the formatting and the extra info.